# How to filter QC test plan grid view to tests in specific folder tree

Tags: quality-center

Given a test plan tree with test cases in folders and subfolders.

How do I filter the grid view to only display all tests in a specific folder tree?

Intention: update a field of these tests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for tests in Test Lab or Test Plan? (The title of this question is different from description)?

You should click on Filter button and define a filter by **Subject** field. There is a dialog box to select proper subject from tree, but you can also tipe it manually in the way like

```
^Subject\Folder\Subfolder^
```

In Test Lab you can do the same but use filter by **Test Set Folder** field

Comment: I meant test plan and fixed the question.